# Is it possible to install a fingerprint reader in a thinkpad T520 that didn't come with one?

Tags: computer-building, thinkpad, fingerprint

I have a Lenovo T520 but I didn't order it with a fingerprinter reader. I was wondering if it is possible to purchase the finger printer reader separately (like this one: [ebay link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Lenovo-ThinkPad-T520-Fingerprint-Reader-Board-48-4KE45-011-55-4KE05-001-/361067118496?hash=item541146ffa0:g:AP0AAOSwwE5WZP~e#viTabs_0), and install it with ease?

Comment: "Ease" is such a relative term.  Does your machine have a cutout in the case for the sensor with a removable cover?  If not, it won't be practical.  You can probably find an external USB-connected unit.  Just make sure it comes with a driver for your machine or that one is available.

Comment: Yes, the computer has a cutout int he case for the sensor. I'm comfortable with taking a laptop apart as well, not my first time. I was just wondering if it is pretty much a matter of plugging in that component from that youtube link or if my motherboard wouldn't be correct?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the components.  You might be able to get specifics from the eBay seller, or even Lenovo tech support.  The signs are promising.

Answer (score 1):

Installing something like that would take a lot of modding, taking the laptop apart, cutting out a slot and any room required, probably buying the correct cable and finding where that connects for the particular model, and all in all would not be recommended, the value would generally be a lot less than the time and risk of killing your computer. Instead a usb fingerprint scanner would be much more viable, such as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HHHP7C).